# Navigation tab position bug on tag pages for tags that have featured questions

Tags: bug, design

When there are featured questions for a tag, the inclusion of the "featured" tab in the header cause the tabs to flow out of position.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

(I'm using Chrome 34.0.1847.131 and Firefox 29.0.1 on OS X 10.9.2.)

Comment: Sorry, missed this on my last pass. Sending over to Jin - thanks for the report :)